# Which part of a self-propelled passenger train (DMU) is safest in an accident?

Tags: trains, safety

My transit system ([Tri-Met](https://trimet.org), metro Portland, Oregon) has the [Portland & Western R. R.](https://www.gwrr.com/railroads/north_america/portland_western_railroad_inc#m_tab-one-panel) (more)[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portland_and_Western_Railroad) run [self propelled commuter coaches](https://trimet.org/wes/index.htm) (diesel multiple units, DMU) on a freight line; sometimes solo, sometimes with an [unpowered control car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_car) coupled to the car with the power pack. The car with the power pack is forward half the time, aft half the time. 
Is it safer to be in the powered coach in the event of derailment or collision? In which part of that coach?
This is different from other question about safety, because they addressed exclusively unpowered coaches; in this situation, we have one car with extra mass (which might help) vs diesel fuel and an attendant fire risk.

Comment: It would depend on the nature of the collision.  So the answer would also depend on the frequency of collisions of various types.  This in turn would depend on what other kinds of trains operate on the system, and on other factors specific to the system.  Are you looking for a general answer or one that applies to the Tri-Met system?

Comment: If one of these trains is in a collision, you're going to know it regardless of which car you're in. The "safest" spot is going to be farthest from the collision, of course. But that won't necessarily keep you out of the hospital.

Comment: For future reference, the correct term to describe the type of train is "diesel multiple unit" or DMU.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, not necessarily. In the Eschede train disaster, the driver didn't even realise until the front locomotive had travelled 1/2 km farther. http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/106269.stm

Comment: @Gnubie True, but this is a quite different sort of train than the light rail train operated in Portland, Oregon, which has only two cars.

Comment: The route in question is *not* light rail, but is a mixed (freight and passenger) line using equipment approved by the FRA for use in mixed traffic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WES_Commuter_Rail

Comment: @phoog I know there's a lot of finished lumber as well as some general cargo, box car, tanker, and containerized, in that rail segment. I bow to your superior wisdom.

Comment: @Randall It's actually both though. Large portions are on conventional rail, and the rolling stock is designed to FRA standards. However, around stations, the rail is at grade and intersections are crossed like light rail, so you do have concerns of getting hit by car traffic.

Answer (score 24):

It's pretty small marginals we're talking about (trains hardly ever crash in the first place), but I don't think the type of car matters as much as *where in the train*.

Most collisions involve the front end of at least one train -- and most derailments involve something going wrong with the first bogie, since that will meet hazards on the track first. So for a two-car train the rear car will be relatively less likely to be directly involved in an accident.

(Diesel fuel is pretty hard to ignite; I've never heard of a train accident where a fuel fire was a determining factor).

Comment: Agreed - getting Diesel to burn takes quite a lot of effort, either heating it beforehand or compressing it - neither of which are likely to happen in a typical train accident. It's also worth pointing out that train crashes are incredibly rare - for example here in the UK it has been over 10 years since a train passenger was killed in a crash.

Comment: True, though I don't think anyone has ever been killed while doing so - evacuating a train between stations is very rare, and usually the power is off when they do so...

Comment: "the rear car will be relatively less likely to be directly involved in an accident" unless most accidents are between two trains on the same track, in which case the front of one train will collide with the rear of another.

Comment: @phoog: Such accidents involve at least as many train fronts as they involve train backs, so they cannot cancel out an imbalance from other kinds of accident, no matter how many there are of each kind.

Comment: Fuel fires have caused fatalities in multiple accidents. Example: [Ladbroke Grove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladbroke_Grove_rail_crash), [Glendale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_Glendale_train_crash), [Shields Junction](http://www.railwaysarchive.co.uk/docsummary.php?docID=507)

Comment: Just to clarify one point: in most reported cases in which one train collides with the rear of another, the collision occurs because the front train is stationary. The other comments here seem to be implying that collisions in this category have low-impact speeds, because both trains are in motion, but usually that isn't the case, hence the rear carriages are at equal risk with the front carriages. We were taught in school that the safest part of a train is the centre coach. Bad news if you're in a two-coach train!

Comment: @Ed999: I'm not sure where you see such an implication in the comments. But in general a rear-ending accident will involve lower _relative_ speeds than a frontal collision, exactly _because_ one of the trains is generally stationary. In a frontal collision with both trains in motion, the relative speed is (to a first approximation) twice as high.

Comment: No, I see nothing suggesting a head-on collision. In the more likely case of both trains travelling in the same direction, a moving collision (entirely possible in the dark, both at night or in a tunnel) may occur when one train catches up to the other, when the relative speed of the trains will be similar. Normally, trains are kept at a minimum safe distance apart, but in the past there have been cases where the safety systems failed.

Comment: @Ed999 I have no idea what your point is. What are you *disagreeing* with?

Comment: Crash from 1918 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbone_Street_Wreck shows that type of the car makes all the difference in the world. Unfortunately, it's not possible to generalize into "powered/unpowered car". 2012 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santiago_de_Compostela_derailment also highlights importance of type of the car, although the one that derailed was not accessible to passengers.

Comment: @Ed999 so obviously you go into the last coach and run to the front the moment the train stops. problem solved.

Comment: Re fuel: The [Lac-Mégantic rail disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lac-M%C3%A9gantic_rail_disaster) involved crude oil (whose ignitability surprised even experts).

Comment: In the UK there has been two derailments this century where at least the front two cars have remained upright and on the tracks with fatalities occurring further down the train.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potters_Bar_rail_accidents
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatfield_rail_crash

Comment: Crude will have all kinds of fractions, some of which will be _very_ volatile. It ain't diesel which is the fuel in use.

Comment: @HenningMakholm but the other train might not be a passenger train.  Similarly, in commuter service in Boston, MA, trains have a locomotive at one end, which is sometimes the front and sometimes the rear, since the trains do not turn around when they reverse the direction of travel.

Comment: @K7AAY the freight trains running on the same line have no locomotives?  That would be odd indeed.

Comment: @phoog "Similarly, in commuter service in Boston, MA, trains have a locomotive at one end, which is sometimes the front and sometimes the rear, since the trains do not turn around when they reverse the direction of travel. " These commuter coaches do not have a locomotive.

Comment: @K7AAY I understand that.  The situation is similar in that one of these coaches may collide with, or be struck by, another train, which could have a locomotive.  If the passenger coach is struck by the locomotive, it could be the back or the front coach. In a high-speed collision with a locomotive, though, it might not matter that much which coach someone is in.

Comment: @DonQuiKong : If you are in a one-carriage (or two-carriage) train, running up the train won't be an option. Seems to me these self-propelled passenger DMU units are as unsafe as it is possible to be. No where to run to, no extensive line of carriages at either end of the train as a buffer to cushion any impact, very vulnerable to being hit by the huge mass and momentum of a high speed locomotive from either direction. About the only safe feature is that a DMU is diesel fuelled, which is less prone to ignite and (unlike electric trains) has no danger of electrocution from downed live wires.

Answer (score 16):

I'll second sitting towards the rear as mentioned in the excellent answer by Henning Makholm (train crashes in the US, as far as I know, are most usually collisions between trains and things that aren't trains that have no business being in the track (eg at level ("grade") crossings); or derailments, both of which are going to affect the front of the train more than the rear).

But I also wanted to add that if your system has seats facing in both directions (I know many American systems have seats all facing the same direction and complicated methods of turning the train or flipping the seats around), it's also much more survivable to sit with your back facing the direction of travel. If you hit something you will be thrown *into* your seat, rather than across the train and into various, much less soft, obstacles or (worse) out of a broken window or door.

In most countries though I wouldn't bother with such things. Rail accidents are rare and if it means ruining your enjoyment of the journey by sitting in a more crowded part of the train or in a seat you don't like (even if it's safer), I'd much prefer to just take the minuscule risk.

Comment: If another train crashes from behind isn't the problem with facing forward just the opposite? Does that happen far less frequently?

Comment: @Mehrdad, far less frequently.  A quick look at British railway accident reports from the past four years shows 22 cases of trains derailing or striking non-train objects, versus two cases of a train striking another train.

Comment: I'd take issue with the definition of "survivable". Trains are not fitted with seat belts, hence if an accident occurs the passenger sitting opposite you will be flung at you, there being nothing to retard his motion as the train stops. It perhaps is safer to sit with your back to the direction of motion, but in an aircraft no one does. Why do airlines allow this, if it is unsafe? Seems to imply that there is actually no safety benefit from sitting facing the rear.

Comment: @Ed999 It would make planes safer but not enough to make it worth while. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/why-are-passenger-seats-not-facing-backward-on-an-airplane

Comment: @ed999 opposite passenger *flung at you*?  Do you investigate a lot of rail accidents?   A crash with *that much* gee-force developing is a rarity indeed.  Train cars have huge mass and are very resistant to changing speed rapidly, this tends to limit jerk and acceleration.   Also do you ride much? Two rows of train seats facing each other are not that common, usually you are looking at the back of the next seat.  Perhaps on your system.

Comment: @Harper In England it is very common, on the East Coast Main Line, for passengers to be sat facing each other. At least half the seats in each carriage have this arrangement. I  think it is probably to allow parents travelling with young children to supervise them properly, but it also provides for better leg room for commuters than the alternative 'airline cabin' arrangement. In a derailment, there is no gradual loss of speed on impact, and the safety systems you describe would not be effective.

Comment: I was referring to a derailment.  A common misconception of accidents is that the moment of the first event, everything stops.  This mentality leads Americans to not wear seat belts.   Outside of hitting a bridge abutment, there's very little that'll stop a derailed train car from careening where it pleases.  It doesn't stop, it may not even drag to a stop as fast as it can brake.

Comment: @Ed999 better to be on the receiving end of the passenger being flung, than to *be* the passenger being flung...

Comment: @Harper "A common misconception of accidents" +100! People (Americans, at least) seem to have an abysmal understanding of the physics of 500,000 tons of moving metal. My step-dad worked for the Union Pacific and said that within 5 years of starting, almost every engineer had killed someone trying to beat a train to the crossing. Very sad.

Comment: Fortunately, their older motor coaches have easy-flip seat backs, and the more modern cars always have some seats with back-to-direction-of-travel.

Answer (score 5):

My first instinct was to go with "sit in the back" as the two (current) answers advise. However, since they're already here, I'll add a counter point that sometimes there is a collision between two trains that are on the same block of track when they shouldn't be.

Being in the back of train would be the best-bet if you're in the train *doing* the rear-ending, however, being in the *front* of the train if you in the one *being* rear-ended is going to be your best bet.

i.e. There's not much you can do to protect yourself in a train accident. Much like commercial aircraft operations, the odds of being in an accident in the first place are pretty darn small. The best you can do is not stress over something that has an incredibly small chance of happening.

*NOTE: Advice does not apply if the operator has an unacceptably high accident rate. In that case, take the bus.*

Comment: +1 for the note.  I suspect that the bus may have a higher accident rate than the train, but kudos anyway for breaking outside of the box.  It's easy to forget that.

Comment: Although true, I'd _think_ (but would have to check) that if sitting in one of the coaches that has "first contact", that it would be more survivable to get rear-ended than doing the rear-ending. In other words, sitting in the rear of the train and getting rear-ended doesn't seem as bad as sitting in the front of the train and doing the rear-ending.

Comment: Tri-Met https://trimet.org/wes/index.htm does not operate this train; it's operated by the Portland & Western https://www.gwrr.com/railroads/north_america/portland_western_railroad_inc#m_tab-one-panel for Tri-Met, and it's P&W's right-of-way.

Comment: @K7AAY - close enough... :)

Comment: Maybe it makes a difference if the commuter train crew knows a little more about what the freight crews are doing, since they're on the same payroll? Maybe?